# How to fill the first radio button in a loop?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, radio-button

we're using angularjs, and we want to know how to fill the first radio button in a loop. because the fill is in the last radio button.

```
 <div class="col m6 s12" ng-repeat="p in priceList">
    <p>
       <input class="with-gap" name="subsgroup" type="radio" id="{{p.subsription }}" ng-checked="true" />
       <label for="{{p.subsription}}">{{ p.price | currency }} per {{p.subsription}}</label>
    </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looping through and setting `ng-checked` as you go. Since they're all in the same radio button group, naturally the last one will be the one checked.

You can use `$index` as shown in the example below to check if its the first element and only display a checked radio button for that one. Optionally, you could look at using `$first`.

```
<div class="col m6 s12" ng-repeat="p in priceList">
    <p>
        <input ng-if="$index == 0" class="with-gap" name="subsgroup" type="radio" id="{{p.subsription }}" ng-checked="true" />
        <input ng-if="$index != 0" class="with-gap" name="subsgroup" type="radio" id="{{p.subsription }}" />
        <label for="{{p.subsription}}">{{ p.price | currency }} per {{p.subsription}}</label>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Woshooo, you're welcome. If you this solution works for you could you set this as the selected answer so others viewing the question are aware? Thank you! :)

Comment: Yes, just waiting for 2mins. to set it the correct answer :)